# How can I initialize matrices with sensible indentation in haskell

Tags: haskell, matrix, indentation

I want to get a matrix filled with hard coded values in haskell. However because of the indentation rules in haskell, the only way I have managed to do this is to write the whole matrix on a single line which is hard to read.

```
matrix = [                          
   [1,0,0],
   [0,2,0],
   [0,0,3]
] --parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)

matrix = [ [1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,1] ] --OK
```

What is the recommended way to do this?

Comment: [Johan Tibell's Haskell style guide](https://github.com/tibbe/haskell-style-guide/blob/master/haskell-style.md) may be of interest to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way that the haskell community has sort of decided we like to do our indenting is:

```
matrix = [ [1, 0, 0 ]
         , [0, 2, 0 ]
         , [0 ,0 ,3 ]
         ]
```

or

```
matrix = [ [1, 0, 0 ]
         , [0, 2, 0 ]
         , [0 ,0 ,3 ] ]
```

leading commas is by far the dominating style :)

You can bring the matrix down too

```
matrix =
  [ [1, 0, 0 ]
  , [0, 2, 0 ]
  , [0 ,0, 3 ] ]

matrix =
  [ [1, 0, 0 ]
  , [0, 2, 0 ]
  , [0 ,0, 3 ]
  ]
```

The problem with your example is that only things indented "past the `m`" are considered "still a part of the declaration of matrix".  So for example:

```
matrix = blah
  bloh
bluh
```

the `bluh` is on the same level as the `m`, so haskell sees `bluh` and goes, "welp, this is a new declaration!  we're done with `matrix`!"

Admittedly, the compiler error could be a bit clearer :)

Comment: I am partial to the third style, with one adjustment: putting the final `]` in a separate line, as in the first snippet.

Comment: yeah, that's probably what I'd do too, because it's easy to add fourth, fifth lines that way :)

Comment: I added that fourth option into my answer